# could not import github.com/go-cucumber/allure (no required module provides package "github.com/go-cucumber/allure")compilerBrokenImport

Tags: allure

When attempting to import "github.com/go-cucumber/allure," I encountered the following error: "no required module provides package 'github.com/go-cucumber/allure' (compilerBrokenImport)." Unfortunately, when searching on pkg.go.dev, I received the message: "Oops! We couldn't find 'github.com/go-cucumber/allure.' Please ensure that you've entered the URL correctly, attempt to fetch it following the provided instructions, or consider requesting the addition of 'github.com/go-cucumber/allure' to pkg.go.dev."

Is there any alternative solution available for this issue? Please advise.

I need alternative Solution